# Parts of Textured Mesh look extremely different from other parts

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I have a model and a skin material. When applying the material to the model mesh, everything looks good, except that portions of the mesh look very different:

Explicit image

> [image]

Now, the head is actually made of multiple disconnected meshes that are joined together and have vertices placed on top of each other, so I figured that maybe that was the issue. But selecting all the disconnected parts of the head mesh and merging by distance does nothing. Similar situation with the pelvic region.

I also thought that maybe the vertices had to be adjusted over the image texture in the UV editor, but this didn't make sense because I'm using a uniform skin texture. Rotating parts of the mesh in the uv editor does seem to have an effect on lighting, but in edit mode. In object mode, there's no change at all.

Also, the issues with lighting in the mesh only happen in object mode. In edit mode, these two artifacts don't appear.

What could be going on?

Comment: With the whole mesh (or at least mesh "sections") selected in edit mode, try selecting _Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside_ from the menu at the top of the viewport.

Comment: It has no effect. :( I tried recalculating outside with no effect. Recalculating inside causes the issue to happen above both brows. Merging by distance and then recalculating outside also has no effect. :(

Comment: Yeah, that's strange. You're certain all the sections have the same material? The "off" areas seem to have lower roughness and subsurface values compared to the rest - I thought it was the normals, but if that's not it, my next guess is materials. If it's not that, I'm not sure what else it could be. You might have to try merge by distance again but increase the merge threshold incrementally (by increasing the last digit, not using the arrows - they increase too much) to make sure there are no dupes that weren't caught by the default distance.

Comment: pls provide blend file